# sed error sed: -e expression #1, char 23: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Tags: regex, sed

I am getting an error with sed:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

Here is my script:

```
result=`$(PERL) parse.pl report.log`;   \
echo $$result | sed "s/.*([a-zA-Z0-9._]*).*/\1/p";
```

Basically, the output of my perl script is something like this:

```
ERR: dir/out/file/report/temp.log (23): some error message here
```

What I expect sed to do is to get the path which is dir/out/file/report/temp.log.

But I am stuck on this error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

what am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

It is because, sed treats `(` as character pattern by default. You need to  either,

- Escape the paranthesis,

  ```
  echo $$result | sed "s/.*\([a-zA-Z0-9._]*\).*/\1/p";
  ```
- User extended regular expressions using `-E`

  ```
  echo $$result | sed -E "s/.*([a-zA-Z0-9._]*).*/\1/p";
  ```

---

The regex that you have will not be sufficient to get the directory name from the string. Instead you can write

```
$ sed -E 's/ERR: ([^ ]*).*/\1/g'
```

**Example**

```
$ echo "ERR: dir/out/file/report/temp.log (23): some error message here" | sed -E 's/ERR: ([^ ]*).*/\1/g'
dir/out/file/report/temp.log
```

Comment: I tried the second one, with the -E option, though no error was thrown but it looks like it was not able to get the filepath. Is my regex correct?

Comment: @chrisyo The regex is wrong to get that part of the string. I have updated the answer.